# Is "he/his" for third person standard English when you don't know the person's gender?

Tags: pronouns

I've read and heard that you can use they/their to refer to the person singular (someone, whoever, a student) when you don't know the gender of the person. Is it stand English to only use he/his?

Ex.: Whoever wants to get **his** hair cut should come with me.

A good student does **his** homework.

No one forgets **his** own name.

Thanks

Comment: We have a tag for this [tag:singular-they] which contains much useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern English, you should use they/their, which is called "[singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)." You heard correctly: you can use these when the gender is unknown or when you don't want to grammatically assign a gender.

> - Whoever wants to get **their** hair cut should come with me.
> - A good student does **their** homework.
> - No one forgets **their** own name.

It's common to find "he/his" as gender-unkown pronouns in older writing -- the older the more common -- but this is now decidedly out of favor.

One also occasionally finds "she/her" as gender-unknown pronouns. This was a trend that gained popularity in the age of gender bias recognition and awakening and is still followed, but "they/their" are quickly becoming most standard.